# Unlocking two LUKS partitions with one password using Kernel parameters

Tags: arch-linux, luks, swap

My current setup includes a root partition and a swap partition, both LUKS encrypted. Currently to decrypt them I use the following Kernel paramters: (I am using the `systemd` and `sd-encrypt` initramfs hooks)

```
rd.luks.name=ROOT-UUID=root root=/dev/mapper/root \
rd.luks.name=SWAP-UUID=swap rd.luks.key=/etc/cryptsetup-keys.d/swap.key resume=/dev/mapper/swap
```

I was hoping that the `rd.luks.key` parameter could be used to automatically decrypt my swap partition, but of course, the key is located inside of my root partition, so as to avoid the system trivially decrypting itself ­— So I really need to impose somehow the order in which the partitions get decrypted and mounted, so that the key will be available at the time when swap needs to be unlocked.
However, I believe that I must decrypt and mount the swap partition through Kernel parameters, so that the `resume=` parameter can be set correctly.

At the end of the day, all I really want is to avoid having to enter two passphrases on each bootup.
I would prefer the swap partition to be decrypted through a keyfile, so that I can periodically change its passphrase to a randomly-generated one, potentially automatically, however; I will also suffice with a single passphrase directly unlocking both partitions as long as I am able to resume into swap correctly.

Am I approaching this correctly? Am I missing anything I need or don't need for this process? Any help greatly appreciated.